# How to pass CTRL+C to python paramiko via threading concepts?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko, python-multithreading

I have executed a python-paramiko snippet for certain time **(Timed Activity)** and then sends **CTRL+C** after certain fixed time (keeps on writing some data for that fixed amount of time). Nothing wrong in this, it works absolutely fine.

Now, I would like to do the same thing in much better way. Say, let it keep on writing data until an **activity (un-timed)** is completed. After the activity completed,  I should halt that script or halt the writing data & close the connection. How can i do it ? Do I need to use threads ? Can you help me ?

```
import paramiko

def fun1():
    try:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(ip,username=username,password=password)
        except Exception as err:
            print err
```

**For reading:**

```
while True: #while time.time() - start < 3:
    if session.recv_ready():
        data = session.recv(1024)
        sys.stdout.write(data)
        sys.stdout.flush() # Flushing is important!
    time.sleep(0.001) # Yield CPU so we don't take up 100% usage...
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: Why don't you use `time.time() - start < 3`?

Comment: @User : If I use that, it'll be a timed activity. It should be flexible enough to keep on writing the data. Whenever i want to stop it, i can pass CTRL+C (untimed). Does it sound good ?

Comment: So, do you want to send Control+C over SSH after you pressed Control+C on the running program?

Comment: Complete duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627916/how-to-i-pass-ctrlc-to-python-paramiko-via-threading-concept